# Creating an edit modal in ASP.NET - MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have `Index.cshtml` with the code below

```
@model IEnumerable<Demo.Models.RequestList>

....

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</td>
...
<a class="dropdown-item" onclick="edit(@item.ID)" href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Home", new { id = item.ID })">Edit</a>
}
```

It mean, I get data from DB and show on the table. Each row of the table I create a button for edit.

When I click Edit button, it will `href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Home", new { id = item.ID })`

But now, I want create `Edit modal` or a `@html.partial` on the Modal instead of `href` to a new page. How can I do that?

It is my Edit code.

```
    @model Demo.Models.RequestList

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>RequestList</h4>
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Code, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Code, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Code, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div> 
    ....
 <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Since you already have an action for editing a single item, all you need to do is to call it with ajax and display the result in a modal window that you can create with your client framework of choice.

Comment: Yes, you are going to have to write clientside code to do this.  It is not done in the MVC framework.  You can leave your Edit code as an ActionResult but you will replace your Url.Action("Edit"...) with some onclick event and a handler that can read and pass the id on to the Edit Action and then show your Edit code in a modal.